# RDP into an Ubuntu machine (with sound)

Tags: sound, remote-desktop, ubuntu-studio

I need to set up a remote Linux workstation for basic video editing. To fully achieve this , I have to provide an RDP-like access to the machine, but including the sound. Unfortunately I can't really do much with the client machines (running MS Windows 7) that will be connecting to the workstation, so installing PulseAudio libraries or third-party software is most likely out of question unless there is absolutely no other way of achieving the desired result.

As for the workstation, I want to use Ubuntu Studio 16.04.2 (LTS) as the OS. I tried setting up XRDP, but there are some window scaling issues and most importantly - there is no sound support (at least not without installing additional software on the client machine). Is there an existing solution that could allow logging into the Ubuntu machine remotely via RDP with sound support?

Answer (score 0):

use TeamViewer it has sound and many other goods, though it uses TW server somewhere at Germany, where CIA  resident evil